# Prisma: Error validating datasource `db`: the URL must start with the protocol `postgresql://` or `postgres://`

Tags: prisma

I am trying to deploy my NestJS application with prisma in production. But when launching my server, I have this error:

```
nestjs     | PrismaClientInitializationError: error: Error validating datasource `db`: the URL must start with the protocol `postgresql://` or `postgres://`.
nestjs     |   -->  schema.prisma:11
nestjs     |    | 
nestjs     | 10 |   provider          = "postgresql"
nestjs     | 11 |   url               = env("DATABASE_URL")
nestjs     |    | 
nestjs     | 
nestjs     | Validation Error Count: 1
nestjs     |     at Object.loadEngine (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35591:19)
nestjs     |     at async Object.instantiateLibrary (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35520:5)
nestjs     |     at async Object.start (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35670:5)
nestjs     |     at async Proxy.onModuleInit (/app/dist/prisma.service.js:14:9)
nestjs     |     at async Promise.all (index 0)
nestjs     |     at async callModuleInitHook (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/hooks/on-module-init.hook.js:43:5)
nestjs     |     at async NestApplication.callInitHook (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application-context.js:178:13)
nestjs     |     at async NestApplication.init (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:96:9)
nestjs     |     at async NestApplication.listen (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:155:33)
nestjs     |     at async bootstrap (/app/dist/main.js:8:5) {
nestjs     |   clientVersion: '3.11.1',
nestjs     |   errorCode: 'P1012'
nestjs     | }
```

My docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  nestjs:
    container_name: nestjs
    build:
      context: ./apps/nestjs
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    env_file:
      - ./apps/nestjs/.env
```

My .env :

```
DATABASE_URL="postgres://myUser:myPassword@myHost:myPort/myDB?sslmode=require"
```

What I tried to do :

1. Check that my `.env` was taken into account. When I go into the container, my environment variable exists
2. Try replacing `postgres` to `postgresql`

Any ideas?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Problem solved.

I didn't have to surround the URL with " in my .env..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,

1. Check your **.env** file if the **URI** is good
2. Check the **provider** from your **schema.prisma**
3. try to remove your **node_modules** and reinstall them.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `npm uninstall prisma` then `npm install prisma` and finally `npx prisma generate`.
That worked for me. It will create a new prisma client based on your prisma schema file.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have to put " around your URL but you may need it and it should have worked.
In fact, it is an issue on old docker-compose version. Upgrade it and welcome " back !

Answer (score -1):

For me the problem was a mismatch between versions of Prisma CLI and Prisma Client.

Updating both to the same version solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your env variables are defined in .env and not just .env.local

Answer (score -1):

In ts file replace:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client/edge";
```

**with**

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
```